# Springboot test Insert Jdbc

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

*I am new to Mockito, and trying to understand the concept.

Trying to unit test inserting new record to db using jdbc.

Here is my service; OrderServiceImpl

```
package com.ordermanager.service;

import com.ordermanager.models.Order;
import com.ordermanager.models.OrderRowMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCallback;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService{

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;



    @Override
    public String validateFields(Order order) {
        String err = "";

        if(order.getTicker() == null)
            err = "Ticker is blank. ";
        if(order.getOrderDate() == null)
            err += "OrderDate is blank. ";
        if(order.getQuantity() <= 0)
            err += "Quantity is invalid. ";
        if(order.getPrice() <= 0)
            err += "Price is invalid. ";
        if(order.getDirection() == null)
            err += "Direction is blank. ";

        if(!(order.getDirection().toLowerCase().equals("buy") || order.getDirection().toLowerCase().equals("sell"))) {
            err += "Direction must be either 'buy' or 'sell'. ";
        }

        return err;
    }

    @Override
    public Order getById(int orderId) {

        String sql = "Select OrderId, Ticker, OrderDate, Quantity, Price, Direction from Orders WHERE orderID =?";

        try{
            return (Order) this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,new Object[] {orderId}, new OrderRowMapper());
        }
        catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Order processOrder(Order order) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO `OrderManagement`.`Orders` (`Ticker`,`OrderDate`, `Price`, `Quantity`, `Direction`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        return jdbcTemplate.execute(sql, new PreparedStatementCallback<Order>() {
            @Override
            public Order doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

                ps.setString(1,order.getTicker());
                ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(order.getOrderDate().getTime()));
                ps.setFloat(3,order.getPrice());
                ps.setInt(4,order.getQuantity());
                ps.setString(5,order.getDirection());

                ps.execute();

                return order;
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Here is my Test

```
package com.ordermanager.unit.service;

import com.ordermanager.controller.OrderController;
import com.ordermanager.models.Order;
import com.ordermanager.service.OrderService;
import com.ordermanager.service.OrderServiceImpl;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GetOrderServiceTest {


    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private OrderServiceImpl orderServiceImpl;


    @Test
    public void testInsert(){

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderId(1);
        order.setTicker("MSFT");
        order.setPrice(100);
        order.setQuantity(3);
        order.setDirection("buy");
        LocalDate myDate =LocalDate.parse("2014-02-14");
        order.setOrderDate(Date.valueOf(myDate));


        Order created = orderServiceImpl.processOrder(order);

        assertThat(created.getOrderId() ,equalTo( order.getOrderId()));
    }
}
```

error message I am receiving;

Cannot invoke "com.ordermanager.models.Order.getOrderId()" because "created" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.ordermanager.models.Order.getOrderId()" because "created" is null

Comment: Perhaps the test needs to prepare `jdbcTemplate` to return the created order, .e.g, `when(jdbcTemplate..execute(...)..thenReturn(anOrder);`

Answer (score 0):

Mockito it's used when you wanna test something and assume that it's requirements don't need to be tested. For example, you wanna test a controller class but not the service class, so ou mock the service class to kinda "pretend" that's already working. In your case you don't want to mock anything, you really need to test the service functionalities, so the correct code would be something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GetOrderServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private OrderServiceImpl orderServiceImpl;

    private Order createOrder(int id, String ticker, double price, int quantity, String direction, String date){

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderId(id);
        order.setTicker(ticker);
        order.setPrice(price);
        order.setQuantity(quantity);
        order.setDirection(direction);
        order.setOrderDate(LocalDate.parse(date));

        return order;
    }

    @Test
    void shouldInsert() {

        Order expected = createOrder(1, "Ticker", 1.0, 1, "Direction", "1111-11-11");

        Order actual = orderServiceImpl.processOrder(expected);

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
        assertEquals(expected.getId(), actual.getId());
        assertEquals(expected.getTicker(), actual.getTicker());
        assertEquals(expected.getPrice(), actual.getPrice());
        assertEquals(expected.getQuantity(), actual.getQuantity());
        assertEquals(expected.getDirection(), actual.getDirection());
        assertEquals(expected.getDate(), actual.getDate());
    }
}
```

You can set every attribute of your orders on every single test method, but I recommend you to use the **createOrder()** to make your life easier.